# Files disappear on NTFS partition

Tags: ntfs, files

Strange things are happening: some files randomly disappear.

I use Ubuntu to access files (movies, docs, music) on another partition (ntfs), which is mounted through NTFS Configuration Tool.

First I noticed that some PDFs are missing from my "study" folder, but I thought maybe I deleted them myself. But now two albums are missing from Music folder and I'm sure it's something wrong with Ubuntu. All those files were recently downloaded and modified from Ubuntu and moved to ntfs partition. While on Windows 7 (around two years) I never had this problem before.

So how to prevent this problem? And are there any tools I could use to recover files and check for errors? Thanks.

Comment: If you open a terminal `cd` to a folder where files have disappeared, and run `ls -l`, you should get a list of all files in that folder. Do the disappeared files show up there? If yes, it's a problem with Nautilus.

Comment: I already checked this way and through logging from Win 7. Missing files are not showing up :-(

Comment: Are there any errors in `dmesg` after mounting the disk?

Comment: this does seem to happen not only on NTFS partitions, but in EXT4 too.

Comment: I'm having the same problem

Comment: I caught it happening to my ntfs drive on linux when moving some directories around. It was just eating files, copying half and half just disappears. Good i have backup and later switched to ext4, but what the heck was that..

Comment: i was not messing with hibernation or anything like that, just regular USB use and it happened in 2022.

Answer (score 2):

Try running a file system check in Windows7 on that partition. Hopefully the lost files will magically reappear afterwards.

Comment: Yep, chkdsk helped with some files, restored remained ones with Pandora Recovery. But will Ubuntu mess them up again?...

Comment: Good question. I really don't know if Ubuntu was at fault in your case, though it could be. A relative of mine only uses Windows, but had the same problem with an external hdd. I'd advise running chkdsk once in a while and keeping a backup.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/144720/missing-files-when-windows-7-returns-from-hibernate-w-dual-boot) - this is not actually Ubuntu messing up the files, it's Windows "fixing things up" after booting from hibernation image :)

Generally, modifying other OS's filesystem while it's hibernated is the same as directly messing with the disk device at the block level without the OS knowing - it leads to filesystem corruption because the data on disk goes out of sync with what OS knows about the disk.

Comment: Yes I think you're right. Once Windows forced a filesystem check and deleted lots of my files.

Answer (score 0):

When Windows hibernates, it saves the contents of your computer's memory (RAM) to a file called "hiberfil.sys" on your system's boot drive. This file is used to restore your system to its previous state when it wakes up from hibernation. Therefore, any changes made by other operating systems will be lost.

#### Disable Windows hibernate mode

Step 1: Type  **control panel**  to the search box of Windows 11 and then click the result to open this tool.
Step 2: Display items by large icons and then click  **Power Options**.

Step 3: Click  **Choose what the power button does**  from the left side.

Step 4: Click the  **Change settings that are currently unavailable**  link.

Step 5: Tick the box of  **Hibernate**  under the  **Shutdown settings**  section. (To disable Hibernate, uncheck the box of Hibernate.)

Step 6: Finally, click the  **Save changes**  button.

#### Disable fast startup on Windows

2. Open  **Start**.
3. Search for  **PowerShell**, right-click the top result and select the  **Run as administrator**  option.
4. Type the following command to disable Fast Startup on Windows 11 and press  **Enter**:

```
powercfg /h off
```

#### If none of the above solutions doesn't work!

**Before leaving Ubuntu, be sure to unmount the NTFS drive.**