# Files disappeared in ntfs partition using Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: filesystem, ntfs

I am working with both Windows 7 and Ubuntu in my laptop. While using Ubuntu I usually save a lot of files in my Windows partition (ntfs), which I use as some sort of common storage place between both OSs. The thing is, yesterday some of my files I created on the ntfs partition simply disappeared. Then I came across this post

[Files disappear on NTFS partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49000/files-disappear-on-ntfs-partition)

and ran chkdisk, then the files reappeared perfectly. The problem is that now I don't feel comfortable using Ubuntu because I'm afraid files may disappear.

Is there a way to permanently fix this problem? I thought ntfs issues had already been overcome in the linux kernel.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. All the files created later than some date disappeared and all the files older than that date were restored to previous state.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu One?

Answer (score 1):

This may be caused by Windows "synchronising" its hibernation image with the changed filesystem state.

Have a look at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/144720/missing-files-when-windows-7-returns-from-hibernate-w-dual-boot)

The solution would be not to use hibernation in Windows. Ubuntu is not at fault :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I do believe it has something to do with "Suspend" in Ubuntu or "Hibernate" in Windows 7. I've already stoped hibernating Win7 and the problem did not occur again. However, this is not a definitive solution, since the problem is rare and might happen by some reason other than "Suspend" or "Hibernate". I've been running chkdsk to fix eventual problems, but none have occured so far.

Comment: Just for the record, the problem is still ocurring, but I cant seem to find the cause. Sometimes, when I save a file on a NTFS particion using Ubuntu and restart my lapto to use Win7, the files disappear. Then I run chkdsk to recover them.