# Cannot read NTFS partition while in Ubuntu

Tags: 11.10, filesystem, permissions

([`Translation`](http://translate.google.com/#it|en|Ciao%20a%20tutti%20sono%20un%20nuovo%20utente%20ubuntu%2011.10.%20sto%20riscontrando%20una%20stranezza%3A%20da%20un%20paio%20di%20giorni%20circa%20non%20riesco%20pi%C3%B9%20a%20visualizzare%20i%20dati%20contenuti%20in%20un%20disco%20%28file%20sistem%20ntfs%29%2C%20i%20file%20effettivamente%20ci%20sono%2C%20ma%20ubuntu%20non%20li%20visualizza%20%28da%20windows%20si%20riesce%20a%20visualizzarli%29.%20In%20precedenza%20li%20visualizzavo%20e%20non%20mi%20pare%20di%20aver%20modificato%20impostazioni%20di%20sorta%20%28almeno%20consapevolmente%20%3B-%29%29.%20Qualcuno%20ha%20consigli%20da%20darmi%3F%20Grazie%20in%20anticipo!))

Hello everyone I am a new user Ubuntu 11.10. I'm experiencing an oddity: a couple of days or so I can not see any data contained on a disk (ntfs file system).

The files actually exist, but Ubuntu does not display them (from Windows you can see them). Previously visualized them and I do not think I've changed settings of any kind (at least consciously;-)). Does anyone have advice for me?

(**Orginal**)

Ciao a tutti
sono un nuovo utente ubuntu 11.10. sto riscontrando una stranezza: da un paio di giorni circa non riesco più a visualizzare i dati contenuti in un disco (file sistem ntfs), i file effettivamente ci sono, ma ubuntu non li visualizza (da windows si riesce a visualizzarli).
In precedenza li visualizzavo e non mi pare di aver modificato impostazioni di sorta (almeno consapevolmente ;-)).
Qualcuno ha consigli da darmi?
Grazie in anticipo!

Comment: Can you give us more details? maybe you can take a look at this http://askubuntu.com/questions/72319/files-disappeared-in-ntfs-partition-using-ubuntu-11-10 maybe it could help. Anyway can give you a tip of what info add in your question.

Comment: Have you successfully shut down windows? For example Ubuntu cannot open NTFS partitions, if Windows is hibernated. You could try to mount the partition read only (this works even if the hard drive was not cleanly unmounted from within Windows)

Comment: I'm using a 60GB SSD as 1ary dev (2partitions: 1 for Ubuntu 11.10,ext3 and 1 for Win 7 64 bit ultim. ntfs) and a 2ary HHD 160GB sata (ntfs) for data and swap.I was checking my downloads so I opened the HHD to check my Amule dowloads but No files! I closed Ubuntu, opened Win 7 and checked the HHD and the files are there. I've done the same things many times before, but I always saw files. I never hibernated win or ubuntu, I always close them when I need to switch. I hope these are the kind of detail you need. I love computers a lot but actually I am a beginner!

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)