# Partition errors in Windows 8 after running Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, windows-8, partitioning, data-loss

I have dual boot Windows 8 and Ubunu 13.04 (secure & fast boot off, C:\ win8, D:\ shared partition NTFS, and 2 ext4 partitions for ubuntu \ and \home). When I'm in Ubuntu, everything works fine, but when I start Windows 8 and run "Error checking" there are errors. Windows fixes it, but sometimes files are missing from D:\ or they are corrupted (like 0 B size)...

Fast boot is disabled (bcdedit /set disabledynamictick yes) - no change.

Hibernation disabled (powercfg /h off) - no change.

I have important documents on D:\ drive and I'm afraid to open any of them in Ubuntu and then run Windows 8.

Any ideas...???

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable the "fast startup" feature *in Windows,* as described [on this Windows site](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) (among many others). The "fast boot" feature in the firmware is relatively unimportant. The Windows "fast startup" feature, though, turns the shutdown process into a suspend-to-disk operation. When this is done, filesystems are not properly shut down, so when a filesystem is accessed in Linux, damage can result.

Comment: I disabled both - fastboot in bios and fast startup in windows... I even completely disabled hibernation (powercfg /h off)... still, problem remains... I don't know what else to try...

Comment: Make sure you're not sleeping either.

Comment: Are you shutting down properly? You *must* use a proper software shutdown option in *both* OSes. If you just hit the power button or pull the plug, the filesystems will be left in an inconsistent state, which can result in errors.

Comment: I shut down correctly on both OSs... Fast boot, Fast startup and hibernation disabled... today I booted into windows 8  for 2 minutes, then restarted PC back to Ubuntu and suddenly ubuntu cannot access some files on NTFS partition: "This location could not be displayed... Error when getting information for file... Input/output error..."

Comment: Re-check that you've disabled the Windows fast startup feature. There's also a chance that you've got a hardware problem. This could be a bad cable or a failing hard disk, so running SMART tests on the disk (using `smartctl`, GSmartControl, or Palimpsest Disk Utility) may be worth trying. Another thing to check is the kernel ring buffer: Type `dmesg | tail` to see recent entries after you try to access files on the NTFS volume. There may be some clues about what's going wrong in there.

Comment: first I disabled Fast boot like this: [link](http://www.hecticgeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Disabling-fast-start-up-in-Windows-8.png).
then I disabled hibernation like here [link](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/12/disable-hibernation-windows-8/).
Still I feel like win 8 is starting very fast (same as before I disabled it) - is there a way to check if it is really disable or windows is just saying its disabled...??? BTW I have a hybrid HDD 750GB HDD with 24GB express cache...

Answer (score 1):

Nothing worked... Windows always corrupts files while booting...

So, I found workaround: before I shut down Windows I unmount `D:\` with a `*.bat` file that contains the command

```
mountvol D:\ /D
```

and after I boot into windows again, I use another `*.bat` file with the command

```
mountvol D: 'VolumeName'
```

to mount the drive.

This way windows doesn't have access to `D:\` while shutting down or booting...